# Apache Beam KafkaIO mention topic partition instead of topic name

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

Apache Beam KafkaIO has support for kafka consumers to read only from specified partitions. I have the following code.

```
KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                .withCreateTime(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                .withReadCommitted()
                .withBootstrapServers(endPoint)
                .withConsumerConfigUpdates(new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
                        .put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupName)
                        .put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 5)
                        .put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
                        .build())
                .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
                .withTopicPartitions(List<TopicPartitions>)
```

I have the following 2 questions.

1. How do I get the partition names from kafka? How do I mention it in kafkaIO?
2. Does Apache beam spawn the number of kafka consumers equal to the partition list mentioned during the creation of the kafka consumer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answers myself.

**How do I tell kafkaIO to read from particular partitions?**

kafkaIO has the method `withTopicPartitions(List<TopicPartitions>)` which accepts a list of `TopicPartition` objects.

Topic Partitions are named as sequential numbers starting from zero. Hence, the following should work

```
KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                .withCreateTime(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                .withReadCommitted()
                .withBootstrapServers(endPoint)
                .withConsumerConfigUpdates(new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
                        .put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupName)
                        .put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 5)
                        .put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
                        .build())
                .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
                .withTopicPartitions(Arrays.asList(new TopicPartition(topicName, 0),new TopicPartition(topicName, 1),new TopicPartition(topicName, 2)))
```

To test it out, use `kafkacat` and the following command

`kafkacat -P -b localhost:9092 -t sample -p 0` - This command produces to specified partition.

**Does Apache beam spawn the number of kafka consumers equal to the partition list mentioned during the creation of the kafka consumer?**

It will spawn a single consumer group with the number of consumers as the number of partitions mentioned during the building of the kafka Producer object explicitly.